# Can I use last Codeception version with PHPUnit 5?

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception, php-5.6

I'm working in a project with PHP 5.6, when I try to do a unit test with Codeception the project doesn't work because Codeception use PHPUnit 7 and, therefore, PHP 7.
Is there a way to force the use of PHPUnit 5 with Codeception or other way to solve this?

Comment: I'd note that PHP 5.6 is going end-of-life in sixteen days. Time to upgrade. http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Codeception has support for PHP 5.4+. How are you installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So then you should start to update your project to PHP 7 because PHP 5.6 is end of life on on 1. Jan 2019. The most libs are developed for newer version now. And some dependencies depend on PHP 7.

So i would really suggest to start update your project for security reasons and for better features that you can use in newer versions.